# Fluid Dynamics Proof

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics, index-notation

By considering the Product Rule for
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(F_iF_j\right)$$
Where $F_i = [\underline{F}]_i$, show that if $\underline{\nabla}\cdot\underline{F} = 0$ then
$$\iiint_{\Sigma}\left(\underline{F}\cdot\underline{\nabla}\right)\underline{F}\,dV=\iint_S \left(\underline{F}\cdot\underline{\hat{n}}\right)\underline{F}\,dA$$
For the first part, using the product rule, I have an answer of 
$$F_i \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}F_j = \left(\underline{\nabla}\cdot\underline{F}\right)\underline{F} + 
 \left(\underline{F}\cdot\underline{\nabla}\right)\underline{F}$$
I don't know what else I need to do for this question so can I please have some guidence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. One of the terms from the product rule is 0 by assumption. Hence the integral you're looking for is actually an integral of a divergence, so use the Divergence Theorem.

In full: For each $i$,
$$ ∭_{\Sigma} (F\cdot \nabla F)_i \, dV = ∭_{\Sigma} \nabla \cdot (FF_i)\, dV = ∬_SF_i F\cdot n \, dA $$
which is the result.

Comment: Oh yeah I've fixed that. So, $\underline{\nabla}\cdot\underline{F} = 0$ So that would result to $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(F_iF_j) = (\underline{F}\cdot\underline{\nabla})\underline{F}$$ Now what integral am I looking for? @CalvinKhor

Comment: Oh wait so that is the same as $$\iiint_\Sigma \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(F_iF_j)\,dV = \iint_S(F_iF_j)\,dA$$ Okay so I don't understand how the divergence theorem is applied. How were you able to have $\underline{\hat{n}}$ involved? @CalvinKhor

Comment: @Michael you haven't defined what $\Sigma$ and $S$ are, really. They just have to be the domains as in the Divergence theorem.

Comment: @Michael you're missing the normal vector in the integrand

Comment: where does the normal vector come in? I don't know why it should be there? @CalvinKhor

Comment: @Michael well take a step back and try to see what this 'divergence theorem' thing that I keep saying is... :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have used your answer to help me achieve this:
$$\iiint_\Sigma (\underline{F}\cdot\underline{\nabla})\underline{F}\,dV = \underbrace{\iiint_\Sigma \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}F_j\,dV = \iint_S F_iF_jn_j\,dA}_{\Large\text{By Divergence Theorem}} = \iint_S (\underline{F}\cdot\underline{\hat{n}})\underline{F}\,dA$$

Comment: Thank you for your help Calvin! And double check this is right :) @CalvinKhor

Comment: Yes, there is a slight notation issue since the first integral is a vector but the ones in the middle is expressed in components, but otherwise it is right

Comment: Yeah because I have in my notes that $$\left[(\underline{F}\cdot\underline{\nabla})\underline{F}\right]_i = \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}Fj$$ But yeah I'll just keep this